# How to get the number of children with specific value in firebase android?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image: My Database Screenshot]

I want to get the value of all compounds with the status NOT OK, which you can see in the picture i uploaded. I have tried this, but I failed to get the values. Please help me on creating the correct query for what I want to achieve.

```
mUserCompounds.orderByChild("status").equalTo("NOT OK").addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            long compounds_solved = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
            String output = String.valueOf(compounds_solved);
            Log.d("OUTPUT", "Total not ok " + output);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            long compounds_solved = dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount();
            String output = String.valueOf(compounds_solved);
            Log.d("OUTPUT", "Total not ok " + output);
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

What i wanted to obtain for the compounds_solved is 4. But what I get based on my code is this.

[image: Output Screenshot here]

Answer (score 5):

ChildEventListener will give you the data of the child on which an event occured. So when you get the amount of children on the snapshot you're actually getting the count of the amount of properties. Image, name and status (3).

Use ValueEventListener instead.

```
mUserCompounds.orderByChild("status").equalTo("NOT OK").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        System.out.println(dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount());                        }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                    }
                });
```

Comment: how to get this particular child object

Answer (score 3):

From what I understand, you want to find out how many compounds you have with a status with of 'NOT OK'. The reason you are not seeing 4 is because datasnapshot.getChildrenCount refers to the each data snapshot that passes your query. Ammonia, calcium oxide, carbon monoxide, dihydrogen all come into the onChildAdded one by one. The data snapshot is each of these results. The reason why you see 3 every time is because each compound has 3 attributes. Image, name and status. And that is why you see 3 each time when you call datasnapshot.getChildrenCount().

Firebase currently has no way to 'count' the results from a query. You can achieve what you want in two ways.

1. Create an event value event listener instead, it can be single or not. It does not matter

   ```
   mUserCompounds.orderByChild("status").equalTo("Not ok").addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
       @Override
       public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
           Log.v("result", String.valueOf(dataSnapshot.getChildrenCount()));
       }

       @Override
       public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

       }
   });
   ```

This will allow you to "count" how many compounds have a status of ok or not okay

2. Have another part of your database that keeps track of how many compounds have a status of Not ok and have a status of ok.  It could look like this.

```
|----status
                |------ok : 5
                |------notok:10
```

And you can query this part of the database. Every time the status of a compound changes, you update this part of the database(increment and decrement the counters). And when you want to find out how many compounds have an okay status you can make a reference to root.child("status").child("Not ok") and add a single value event listener

Comment: The second approach is also a good thing for me to do! In that way, i can easily query the status :)

Comment: I think you only upvoting the other answer posted here. XD Nevermind. Happy coding!